# ODOO installation asking for Scaffolding

Tags: odoo, scaffolding

I am new developer on ODOO in installing process system is asking for scaffloding. Can anyone assist me regarding Scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

Here you could find the docs for Odoo scaffolding command line usage:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html#reference-cmdline-scaffold

Example usage:

python ./odoo-11.0/odoo-bin scaffold new_module_name